# Electrical conductivity of complex scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-regularization

I want to compute the conductivity of a complex scalar field in both the symmetric and symmetry broken phases. To define the current operator one needs to couple the matter field to EM gauge field using the minimal coupling, the action will be the famous GL functional:
$$ S=\int d^dx\,d\tau \left\{ |(\nabla-ie\mathbf{A}) \psi|^2 + |\partial_\tau \psi|^2 + r|\psi|^2+u|\psi|^4\right\}$$
The current operator is defined as $\mathbf{j}=-\frac{\delta S}{\delta \mathbf{A}}$ which is:
$$\mathbf{j}=-2e^2|\psi|^2\mathbf{A}+\text{another term}$$ 
Where the other term is the "paramagnetic current" which I do not have any problems with. The response function (which eventually will give us the conductivity if we divide it by $\omega$) is then defined as:
$$ K_{\alpha \beta}(x-x')=\frac{\delta}{\delta A_\beta(x')}\langle j_\alpha (x) \rangle|_{\mathbf{A}=0}=-2e^2\langle \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x)\rangle \delta(x-x')\delta(\tau-\tau')+ \text{paramagnetic part}$$
My problem is the first "diamagnetic" current. Its contribution to conductivity (after doing a bit of calculations) will be proportional to $\langle \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x)\rangle$ where $x$ is an arbitrary point.

Now, for the symmetry broken phase everything is okay (at least to the lowest level approximation), since in this phase we have $\psi(x)=-\frac{r}{u}+\text{fluctuations}$ we will get the London equation for a superconductor. But for the symmetric phase ($r>0$), we need to consider the effect of fluctuations, so we have to find:
$$ \langle \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x)\rangle= \int dk^d \, d\omega \, \frac{1}{\omega^2+k^2+r}\,\,\,\,\, (T=0) $$
$$ \langle \bar{\psi}(x)\psi(x)\rangle= T\sum_{\omega_n=2n\pi T} \int dk^d  \frac{1}{\omega_n^2+k^2+r}\,\,\,\,\, (T\ne0) $$
The problem is that the papers say at zero temperature this term vanishes which I find really peculiar since the integrand in above expression is positive definite and one can calculate these integrals. For example the first one is proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+r}}$. 
In papers the authors do the calculation for the $T\ne 0$ case. Basically, they introduce a factor of $1=\frac{\partial k_x}{\partial k_x}$ in the integrand and integrates by parts and one them states that "The surface terms vanish in dimensional or lattice regularization" and the remaining term will be zero at $T=0$. This integration by parts is done in the other paper as well. But this integration by parts seems quite unnecessary to me, while neglecting the surface term (since in arbitrarily large dimensions it is not zero) is obviously not correct. I understand that this integral  has a UV divergence, but in condensed matter there is always a finite upper cutoff and we do not need to be worried about that. But apparently here a kind of renormalization/regularization is being done. I know that this integral is a one-loop integral, but our theory is free (neglecting the $|\psi|^4$ term).

So my main question is why should we abandon the regular way of doing the integral (with and upper cutoff, of course) and instead use something like dimensional regularization. Also I would like to mention that my knowledge about renormalization is limited to the Wilsonian approach and I do not know much about the "field theoretic" viewpoint.

The two papers are:

https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.56.8714
https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.48.3316

Comment: The only thing I've ever seen on this is here equ 4.48
https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/kintheory/four.pdf

Hope it helps mate.